# Probability of two die not rolling $1$ or $2$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Probability of two dice not rolling $1$ or $2$.
Let $A$ be the probability of rolling $1$
Let $B$ be the probability of rolling $2$
My thoughts. It is the same as

$$1-P(A \text{ or } B)$$

$$P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \text{ and } B)$$

where

$$P(A)=P(B)=1/6$$
$$P(A \text{ and } B)=1/36$$

Is this right thinking?

Comment: If, say, $A$ is the event "the first die comes up $1$ or $2$" then $P(A)=\frac 13$.    Otherwise your logic is sound, but it's unnecessarily complicated.  The probability that the first die comes up $>2$ is $\frac 46=\frac 23$ same for the second.  Hence the answer is the product, $\frac 49$.

Comment: I see, I had $A$ be the probability of rolling $1$ and Let $B$ be the probability of rolling $2$ which is wrong

Comment: $P(A\text{ and }B)=2/36$

Comment: @barakmanos Wouldn't $P(A \ \text{and} \ B)=\frac 2 6*\frac 2 6=\frac 4 {36}=\frac 1 9$?

Comment: The first half is true, but $P(A)\neq 1/6$, since you are rolling two dice, so you can get a $1$ on either or both dice.

Comment: @NobleMushtak: There are $2$ such combinations: $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$. Hence the probability is $2/36$. Over all, the answer is $(12+12-2)/36$.

Comment: @barakmanos What about $(1, 1)$ or $(2, 2)$?

Comment: @NobleMushtak: Sorry, you're correct :) ... (also in my following comment - should be "$-4$" instead of "$-2$")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@lulu](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715768/probability-of-two-die-not-rolling-1-or-2/1715788#comment3501845_1715768) points out a very easy way to solve this problem. However, your way of solving it is more interesting, so let's keep going with this logic.

What you did wrong is that you set the events of $A$ and $B$ wrong. $A$ should have been the event in which the first die rolled a $1$ or a $2$ and $B$ should have been the event in which the second die rolled a $1$ or a $2$. Thus, we have the following:

$$P(A)=P(B)=\frac 2 6=\frac 1 3$$
$$P(A \ \text{and} \ B)=P(A)*P(B)=\frac 1 9$$
$$1-P(A \ \text{or} \ B)=1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \ \text{and} \ B))=1-\left(\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3-\frac 1 9\right)=1-\frac 5 9=\frac 4 9$$

The last line gives us our answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is logically okay, but the numbers you are using are wrong. The odds of rolling a $1$ with two dice is not $1/6$, rather it is $11/36$. Instead of having the events be the numbers, they should be the rolls. So, $A$ is the first die being a $1$ or a $2$ and $B$ is the second die being a $1$ or a $2$. These both have $p=1/3$. Then applying your equations will yield the right answer.

This is one of their cases where counting comes greatly in handy.

There are six ways to roll $(1,x)$, six ways to roll $(2,x)$, six ways to roll $(x,1)$, and six ways to roll $(x,2)$. This double counts the pairs $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$. So there are $20$ ways to roll a $1$ or a $2$, meaning the odds of not doing so are $16/36=4/9$

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. The probability of getting on one in two dice rolls in $11/36$. You've counted snake eyes (two ones) twice.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks

Comment: Now the first sentence is correct but the later probability $p$ is wrong; it was correct before the edit.

Comment: Yes, the rest of your answer was originally correct - the odds of getting one or two on a single die is $1/3$, not $11/36$.

Comment: There we go, made it in the end :P

Answer (score 0):

I noticed after writing this that lulu already posted this exact solution
in a comment, so this is a community wiki response.

---

If $A$ is the event "roll $1$ on either of the two dice" and
$B$ is the event "roll $2$ on either of the two dice"
then your formula $1-P(A \text{ or } B)$ is correct.
But I think that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are each as hard to compute
as the original problem, so you might as well skip those steps.

I would suggest instead the following events:

$$ G = \text{the first die is neither $1$ nor $2$,}$$
$$ H = \text{the second die is neither $1$ nor $2$.}$$

Then the probability you want is $P(G \text{ and } H)$.
Since the dice roll independently,

$$P(G \text{ and } H) = P(G) \times P(H).$$